# Как вставить шрифт в word документ?

Tags: шрифты, ms-word

Я нашёл в интернете шрифт, который хочу использовать при написании текста в документе Word.
Я могу этот шрифт добавить в Windows. Но, если я отправлю этот документ другому человеку, у которого этот шрифт не установлен, то что будет?

Что надо: чтобы человек, который получил этот документ, видел текст в корректном виде, без дополнительной установки шрифтов в Windows.

Это возможно? Если да, то как?

Comment: Вопрос явно не по теме. Тем не менее, можете просто сохранить файл в pdf.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или системному администрированию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внедрите шрифт, если вы хотите поделиться документом.

Установив новый шрифт, вы сможете использовать его только на своем компьютере и принтере. Если вам нужно поделиться документом, содержащим новый шрифт, с каким-либо человеком, такой шрифт на другом компьютере отображаться не будет (только если этот шрифт не установлен на другом компьютере). Чтобы решить эту проблему, внедрите шрифт в документ; в этом случае шрифт будет отображаться на любом компьютере. Имейте в виду, что внедрение шрифта в документ приведет к увеличению размера файла документа (так как он будет включать файлы шрифтов).

- В Word нажмите «Файл» – «Параметры».
- Нажмите «Сохранение».
- Поставьте флажок у «Внедрить шрифты в файл».
  В выпадающем меню выберите открытый документ.

Подумайте, хотите ли вы внедрить только те знаки, которые используются в текущем документе. Это позволит вам уменьшить размер файла документа, особенно если вы используете только несколько знаков нового шрифта.

Сохраните и поделитесь документом с другими пользователями. Шрифты будут автоматически внедрены в документ при его сохранении.

Источник: [https://ru.wikihow.com/добавить-шрифт-в-Microsoft-Word](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%B2-Microsoft-Word)